# How to change background color via javascript?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

how to change background color on `mouseout` event? Here's my code, thanks:

```
<div onmouseout="colorBack(id)">Hi everyone</div>

<script>
function colorBack(x){
id.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You must specify the desired behavior of the code together with saying "it is not working". We can't help without knowing _what_ should the code do.

Comment: Maybe `document.getElementById("id").style.backgroundColor="red";` ? Or `onmouseout="colorBack(this)"`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your question is little bit unclear. Let me assume this is what you are intending to do . If it is about backgroundColor. set backgroundColor property from Javascript.

```js
function colorBack(){
       document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
```

```html
<div id="div1" onmouseout="colorBack()">Hi everyone</div>
```

With Jquery it's even more elegant

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
      $( "#div1" ).mouseout(() => {
          $( "#div1" ).css("background-color", "red");
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Hi everyone</div>
```

Hope It helps!

Answer (score 1):

you are welcome:

```html
<div id="myDiv" onmouseout="colorBack()">Hi everyone</div>

<script>
function colorBack(){
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks so much for all the answers guys....I also found out that this works also....

```
<div onmouseout="colorBack(this)">Hi everyone</div>

<script>
function colorBack(x){
x.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
</script>
```